# Linking DataTables with sql database using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, datatables

I hope you can help me because I'm driving mad about this question.
I'm not experienced with Node, Ajax and DataTables, so this is likely a my fault.
I have an html table linked to Datatables. On load document I send a POST request to get data from an MySQL database. If I popolate DataTable with row.add() method all works fine, but if the table grows I could have some slowdowns with this system, so I would like to link the DataTable table with the database so that the program loads only the records to show. Now problem starts.
In my Node file, if I return sql data like so:

> res.json(result);

my DataTable shows all the data, but table hasn't right number of record (below the table shows "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries (filtered from NaN total entries)" and, even worst, the table has infinite pages, all displaying the same data (the first 10 records).
If instead I return an ajax:

```
ret = JSON.stringify({
    "draw": req.body.draw,
    "recordsTotal": result[0]['COUNT(cf)'],
    "recordsFiltered": result[0]['COUNT(cf)'],
    "data": dati
});
res.send(ret);
```

DataTables shows the correct number of records in the info line at bottom of table, but no data is displayed.
In console I show the ret object and it seems all right. I'm no idea what to do now.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved!!! It's incredible after near 2 days of attempts.
In html file I put in DataTables ajax :

```
[...]
dataSrc: 'dati',
[...]
```

Then in my Nodejs file:

```
ret = JSON.stringify({
    "draw": req.body.draw,
    "recordsTotal": result[0]['COUNT(cf)'],
    "recordsFiltered": result[0]['COUNT(cf)'],
    "dati": dati
});
res.send(ret);
```

and all works fine.